# Android studio doesn't see unit tests

Tags: android-studio, gradle, junit4

I updated Android studio to 3.4. And then, when I run tests by gradle (testDebugUnitTest -p app), gradle compiles sources and writes to log "test events were not received". If I run tests by button "Run tests in project" or write command "test -p app", everything works ok. The problem appears only with command "testDebugUnitTest". What's the problem?

Comment: Can confirm the issue after upgrading to AS 3.4, running from project tree works fine (since it's not a Gradle task)

Comment: Android studio unit testing is a flaky mess. If only there was some way they could check if it is working before they ship it.